# what is difference between oracle instant client and oci?

Tags: oracle

I've been reading upon the definitions of oracle instant client and oci but being new to oracle database having a bit of difficult time to understand what they are/for. I would appreciate someone can clarify the difference of two. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCI is short for "Oracle Call Interface". It's essentially the API that defines how program (a "client") can communicate with the database server.

The instant client provides an implementation of the OCI that can be used by other programs, so that they don't have to implement the communication layer. It is e.g. used by SQL*Plus or other client applications.

Comment: so oracle instant client is type of jdbc driver then?

Comment: @DaeYoung: no, the JDBC driver is something different. It doesn't use the OCI interface, it implements that internally and doesn't depend on the Oracle client being installed. The instant client is more like the ODBC driver

Comment: bear with me please for one more question. Oracle instant client needs to be installed on a client machine in order to use oci driver? If I use oracle thin driver (jdbc?) I don't need to install any Oracle program such as instant client. Did I understand right? Thank you!

Comment: @DaeYoung: correct. If you use the Oracle JDBC (thin) driver, all you need is the driver's jar file and a Java runtime.

Comment: I'd appreciate your reply and answer. Have a blessed day!

Comment: It might be good to be aware that the Oracle Instant Client is a minimalistic version of the the also available full version, known as just "Oracle Client".   The instant client contains only the bare minimum of components to allow interaction with other software using OCI - in most cases not even including an installer. The small footprint makes it ideal for simple application deployments.  The Oracle Client is bloated with an installer, libraries, tools and docs that may be required by certain software or just convenient to have on your machine, particularly if you are an IT processional.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Instant Client is a light-weight software which helps to run OCI, OBDBC, Pro*C, JDBC without installing full Oracle client.  In other hand the Oracle Call Interface (OCI) is an application programming interface (API) that allows applications written in C to interact with one or more Oracle Servers.
For details:
[What is Oracle's instant client and how do I install it?](https://kb.berkeley.edu/page.php?id=23108)
[Introduction to Oracle Call Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a95497/ch1.htm)

Comment: The JDBC driver doesn't need an Oracle client (at least not the thin driver which is recommended by Oracle)

Comment: Applications but also libraries written in C, which notably enables interaction with OCI from software written in other languages, even interpreted languages such as PHP, Ruby and Python.